# Preventing A User from Filling Google Form with a different email

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a google form where respondents fill the short answer field with their names and have enabled the Limit to 1 response settings. Also I have a response validation which uses regular expression to check for a particular name. I want to ensure that if a respondent fills the form, he is prevented from filling the form again with a different email. I don't want to use emails for the regex response validation. I used the script below, but it gives Type Error message "Cannot read properties of null(getSheetByName)". The Google spreadsheet that I am using has only one sheet, I have renamed elections. And the first column in that sheet contains the values for the short answer responses.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

    // Get the form response object
    var formResponse = e.response;

    // Get the item responses array
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

    // Get the value of the first item response (assuming it is the short answer)
    var shortAnswer = itemResponses[0].getResponse();

    // Get the form response spreadsheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    // Get the sheet where the responses are stored
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

    // Get the range of the first column (assuming it is the short answer column)
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);

    // Get the values of the first column as an array
    var values = range.getValues();

    // Loop through the values and check for duplicates
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            // If the value matches the short answer, delete the row
            if (values[i][0] == shortAnswer) {

                sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);

                // Break the loop
                form.setCustomClosedFormMessage(
                        "This name has already voted. No multiple voting is allowed"
                );

                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Google Forms does **NOT** support real-time dynamic lookup to Google sheets. That is, your basic premise is not valid. The specific error message is because the script is bound to the form, so `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` is invalid and returns null. FWIW, if your response sheet has been renamed to "elections", then you would use `getSheetByName("elections")`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, Google Forms does not a feature allowing for a dynamic, real-time look from Forms to Sheets.

The following script is offered as an alternative:

- bound to the linked spreadsheet
- triggered by `onFormSubmit`
- when a Form submission is received, the script looks for a matching name in the "Names" column
- if/when a match is found, the script sets the background colour to "red" to highlight the duplicates.

---

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  
  // Get the response values
  var values = e.values

  // get the submitted row and value
  var submittedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var submittedName = values[1]
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the submitted row = "+submittedRow+", submitted name = "+submittedName)

  // test for a match using a loop
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("elections")
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  // convert data from 2D array to 1D array
  var names = data.map(function(e){return e[1];})
  
  // use a loop to find a match
  // change background to highlight duplicate
  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    if (submittedName === names[i]){
      // found a match
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Found a match. i="+i)
      sheet.getRange((i+1),2).setBackground("red")
    }
    else{
      // no match
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: NO match. i="+i)
    }
  } 
}
```